# How can I re-render to display changes without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need help with this bug on my MERN website as I can't figure out how to fix this step on my own.

Every time the users make changes to the backend, I want to re-render it and display it on the UI - without having to refresh the page.

But in my case, everything is working as I expected but there is still 1 last problem:

**The process:**

- On begin, the website will display a `foodList` table with all data from the backend.
- When the users use the **Filter & Search Bar** to find what they want to see. Behind the scenes, it will make a search from filtering out the items in `foodList` array and then put it to the `searchedFood` array. All the **search results** will be returned in the `searchedFood` table.
- On **searching**, the page will hide the `foodList` table and display the `searchedFood` table.
- When users click on the `clearSearch` button, it will bring the `foodList` data table back and hide the `searchedFood`.

**What's working:**

- When I make changes on the `foodList` table, it will re-render and display the changes instantly. It will also re-render the `searchedFood` table when I try to search for that changed item after - all without having to refresh the page.
- When I search for an item and then make changes on a searched item (Which is on the `searchedFood` table) - it will re-render and display the changes instantly.

**What's not working:**

- But then I click the `clearSearch` button to return to the full `foodList` table. The changes I just made in `searchedFood` won't re-render automatically on `foodList` - I need to refresh the page in order to see the changes I've made.

As I understand, there's something missing in the return to the `foodList` table step that isn't triggering the re-render. But what can we do and how to implement it in my code?

---

**Demo:**
Watch my short demo video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rq-Njd-MZ8SdpiS2LP3M4758MpgBGO3k/view?usp=sharing)

##### My code

**- App.js**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
export default function App() {
  const [foodName, setFoodName] = useState('')
  const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState('no')
  const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState('$')
  const [foodUrl, setFoodUrl] = useState('')
  const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([])

  const [searchedFood, setSearchedFood] = useState([])
  const [noResult, setNoResult] = useState(false)

  // Read from db:
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://project.herokuapp.com/read")
      .then((response) => {
        setFoodList(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`The error is: ${error}`)
        return
      })
  }, [])
  
  // Add Food to list:
  const addToList = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
      await Axios.post(
        "https://project.herokuapp.com/insert", 
        {
          foodName: foodName,
          isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
          priceRange: priceRange,
          foodUrl: foodUrl,
        }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          setFoodList([...foodList, { _id: response.data._id, foodName: foodName, isVegetarian: isVegetarian, priceRange: priceRange, foodUrl: foodUrl }])
          setFoodName('')
          setIsVegetarian('no')
          setPriceRange('$')
          setFoodUrl('')
        })
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(`There was an error while trying to insert - ${err}`)
      }
    }


    // Paginate states:
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const [foodPerPage] = useState(10)
    
    // Get current food:
    const indexOfLastFood = currentPage * foodPerPage
    const indexOfFirstFood = indexOfLastFood - foodPerPage
    const currentFood = foodList.slice(indexOfFirstFood, indexOfLastFood)
    const currentSearchedFood = searchedFood.slice(indexOfFirstFood, indexOfLastFood)
    
    // Pagination:
    const paginate = (pageNumber) => {
      setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
    }
  
  return (
    <section>
      <FilterSearch
        foodList={foodList}
        searchedFood={searchedFood}
        setSearchedFood={setSearchedFood}
        noResult={noResult}
        setNoResult={setNoResult}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
      {noResult ? <ResultNotFound/>
        :
          <FoodListTable
            foodName={foodName}
            priceRange={priceRange}
            isVegetarian={isVegetarian}
            foodUrl={foodUrl}
            foodList={foodList}
            setFoodList={setFoodList}
            currentFood={currentFood}
            searchedFood={searchedFood}
            setSearchedFood={setSearchedFood}
            currentSearchedFood={currentSearchedFood}
            totalFood={foodList.length}
            totalSearchedFood={searchedFood.length}
            currentPage={currentPage}
            paginate={paginate}
            noResult={noResult}
            foodPerPage={foodPerPage}
          />
      }
    </section>
  )
}
```

**- FilterSearch.js**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
export default function FilterSearch(props) {
  const [textSearch, setTextSearch] = useState('')
  const [priceDropdown, setPriceDropdown] = useState('')
  const [vegDropdown, setVegDropdown] = useState('')

  // Handle Search button:
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Search logic:
    const newSearch = props.foodList.filter((food) => {
      if (textSearch !== '' && vegDropdown === '' && priceDropdown === '') {
        return (
          Object.values(food)[1].toLowerCase().includes(textSearch.toLowerCase())
        )
      } else if (// Other conditions) {
          // Other filter logic in here
      } else {
        return food
      }
    })
    props.setSearchedFood(newSearch)
    if (!newSearch.length) {
      props.setNoResult(true)
    } else {
      props.setNoResult(false)
      props.paginate(1)
    }
  }


  // Clear search:
  const clearSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    props.setSearchedFood([])
    setTextSearch('')
    setPriceDropdown('')
    setVegDropdown('')
    props.setNoResult(false)
    props.paginate(1)
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <form>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Find your favorites" name="text-search" autoComplete="off" value={textSearch} onChange={(event) => {setTextSearch(event.target.value)
          }} />
          <div>
            <select name="veg-dropdown" value={vegDropdown} onChange={(event) => {setVegDropdown(event.target.value)}} >
              <option disabled value=''>Options</option>
              <option value='no'>Non-veg</option>
              <option value='yes'>Vegetarian</option>
            </select>
            <select name='price-dropdown' value={priceDropdown} onChange={(event) => {setPriceDropdown(event.target.value)}} >
              <option disabled value=''>Prices</option>
              <option value='$'>$</option>
              <option value='$$'>$$</option>
              <option value='$$$'>$$$</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          {(textSearch || priceDropdown || vegDropdown) !== '' && 
            <button onClick={clearSearch}><MdClear /></button>
          }
          <button onClick={handleSearch}><HiSearch /></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**- FoodListTable.js**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

export default function FoodListTable(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Food name
                        </th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>
                            Action
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <body>
             // Return a table with data from searchFood on search: 
                    {props.searchedFood.length > 0 ? props.currentSearchedFood.map((val) => {
                        return (
                            <FoodListRow
                               val={val}
                               key={val._id} 
                               foodName={val.foodName}
                               isVegetarian={val.isVegetarian}
                               priceRange={val.priceRange}
                               foodUrl={val.foodUrl}
                               foodList={props.foodList}
                               setFoodList={props.setFoodList}
                               searchedFood={props.searchedFood}
                               setSearchedFood={props.setSearchedFood}
                               currentSearchedFood={props.currentSearchedFood}
                            />    
                        )
                    }) : props.currentFood.map((val) => { // If not on search, return a table with data from foodList:
                        return (
                            <FoodListRow
                               val={val}
                               key={val._id}
                               foodName={val.foodName}
                               isVegetarian={val.isVegetarian}
                               priceRange={val.priceRange}
                               foodUrl={val.foodUrl}
                               foodList={props.foodList}
                               setFoodList={props.setFoodList}
                               searchedFood={props.searchedFood}
                               setSearchedFood={props.setSearchedFood}
                               currentSearchedFood={props.currentSearchedFood}

                            />
                        )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            // Display different Pagination on searched table and food list table:
            {props.searchedFood.length > 0 ? 
                <Pagination foodPerPage={props.foodPerPage} totalFood={props.totalSearchedFood} paginate={props.paginate} currentPage={props.currentPage} />
                :<Pagination foodPerPage={props.foodPerPage} totalFood={props.totalFood} paginate={props.paginate} currentPage={props.currentPage} />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**- FoodListRow.js**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

export default function FoodListRow(props) {
    // Edit food name:
    const [editBtn, setEditBtn] = useState(false)
    const handleEdit = () => {
        setEditBtn(!editBtn)
    }

    // Update Food Name:
    const [newFoodName, setNewFoodName] = useState('')
    const updateFoodName = (id) => {
        if (newFoodName) {
            Axios.put("https://project.herokuapp.com/update", {
                id: id,
                newFoodName: newFoodName,
            })
            .then(() => {
                props.searchedFood.length > 0 ?
                props.setSearchedFood(props.searchedFood.map((val) => {
                    return (
                        val._id === id ? 
                        {
                            _id: id,
                            foodName: newFoodName,
                            isVegetarian: props.isVegetarian, priceRange: props.priceRange, 
                            foodUrl: props.foodUrl,
                        } : val
                    )
                })) : props.setFoodList(props.foodList.map((val) => {
                    return (
                        val._id === id ? 
                        {
                            _id: id,
                            foodName: newFoodName,
                            isVegetarian: props.isVegetarian, priceRange: props.priceRange, 
                            foodUrl: props.foodUrl,
                        } : val
                    )
                }))
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(`Update name failed: ${error}`))
        }
    }
    

    // Delete food:
    const deleteFood = (id) => {
        const confirm = window.confirm(`This action cannot be undone.\nAre you sure you want to delete this dish?`); 
        if(confirm === true){ 
          Axios.delete(`https://project.herokuapp.com/delete/${id}`)
          .then(() => {
            props.searchedFood.length > 0 
            ? props.setSearchedFood(props.searchedFood.filter((val) => {
                return val._id !== id
            }))
            : props.setFoodList(props.foodList.filter((val) => {
                return val._id !== id
            }))
          })
        }
    }

    return (
        <tr key={props.val._id}>
            <td>
                {props.val.foodName}
                {props.val.isVegetarian}
                // Display input field on Edit Mode:
                {editBtn && 
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="edit"
                            placeholder="New food name.."
                            autoComplete="off"
                            onChange={(event) => {setNewFoodName(event.target.value)}}
                        />
                        <button
                        onClick={() => updateFoodName(props.val._id)}
                        >
                            ✓
                        </button> 
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
            <td>{props.val.priceRange}</td>
            <td>
                <a 
                    href={props.val.foodUrl} 
                >
                    
                </a>
                <button 
                    onClick={handleEdit}
                >
                    ✏️
                </button>
                <button 
                    onClick={() => deleteFood(props.val._id)}
                >
                    ❌
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Comment: If your server isn't pushing out updates to subscribers then your frontend needs to either (1) repull data after the API request to update data in the backend or (2) update its local cache of the data with what it updated to the backend.

Comment: @DrewReese I think I'm pulling the data from the backend 
 after the `Axios` calls and in my code above, right? But I'm stuck with the last step when I click on `clearSearch` and it returns to the `foodList` table. How to perform re-render on that stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you set EITHER the `foodList` OR the `searchedFoodList` in your `updateFoodName` function right here:

```js
const updateFoodName = (id) => {
  if (newFoodName) {
    Axios.put("https://project.herokuapp.com/update", {
      id: id,
      newFoodName: newFoodName,
    })
      .then(() => {
        props.searchedFood.length > 0 // <-- HERE
          ? props.setSearchedFood(/* ... */)
          : props.setFoodList(/* ... */);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(`Update name failed: ${error}`));
  }
};
```

What you really want to do is update both either way:

```js
const updateFoodName = (id) => {
  if (newFoodName) {
    Axios.put("https://project.herokuapp.com/update", {
      id: id,
      newFoodName: newFoodName,
    })
      .then(() => {
        // NO IF HERE
        props.setSearchedFood(/* ... */)
        props.setFoodList(/* ... */);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(`Update name failed: ${error}`));
  }
};
```

If you don't update both, you will not see the changes when `foodList` is shown, because the new data never had a chance to get there.

---

If I can propose changes: I would only ever change the `foodList` and calculate the filtered list using a filter state on every change. This way, you only ever have to change data in one place, which would have avoided confusions like this.

Here is a small prototype of what I would mean:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  const filteredFoodList = useMemo(() => foodList.filter(/*...*/), [
    foodList,
    filter
  ]);

  return (
    filteredFoodList.map(/*...*/)
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Maurice, you saved my day!  The solution works and I definitely made it more complex this way. I'm really interested in using the `useMemo()` solution. May I ask what can we put inside the `foodList.filter(// Here)`

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped you! :) The filter function would be something similar to what you have already. Keep in mind that this example is just stripped down to the essentials, you would probably have to add more code to it, because you do not **only** have a text filter, but also some drop-downs as it seems. The important part is that you should pass your filter state up to where your data resides and then recalculate the actually shown data whenever the data changes, or the filter changes (that's why `useMemo` is used). That way, you simply **can't** get inconsistent data. @Julz